# bootstrap empty field validation use for other validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I downloaded a bootstrap theme for my site and it has a simple but beautiful validation for a required field. When the field is not filled in, it displays a red exclamation mark on the back of the field and when you hover over it, it display's the error message inside of the field.

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-10" data-validate = "Username is required">
  <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <span class="focus-input100"></span>
  <span class="symbol-input100">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.validate-input {
  position: relative;
}

.alert-validate::before {
  content: attr(data-validate);
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #c80000;
  border-radius: 14px;
  padding: 4px 25px 4px 10px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;

  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  text-align: left;

  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.alert-validate::after {
  content: "\f06a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  color: #c80000;
  font-size: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 13px;
}

.alert-validate:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
   .alert-validate::before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

And the JQuery:

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";

/*==================================================================
[ Validate ]*/
var input = $('.validate-input .input100');

$('.validate-form').on('submit',function(){
    var check = true;

    for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if(validate(input[i]) === false){
            showValidate(input[i]);
            check=false;
        }
    }

    return check;
});


$('.validate-form .input100').each(function(){
    $(this).focus(function(){
       hideValidate(this);
    });
});

function validate (input) {
    if($(input).attr('type') == 'email' || $(input).attr('name') == 'email') {
        if($(input).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if($(input).val().trim() == ''){
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function showValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

    $(thisAlert).addClass('alert-validate');
}

function hideValidate(input) {
    var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

    $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-validate');
    $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-minimum-validate');
}



})(jQuery);
```

Now, I would love to use this code to do other validation as well. So for example, if the username is filled in, but it's larger then the maximum amount of characters, I would like to change the error message stated in data-validate in the HTML and have it display that message. Or if the password does not contain special characters or numbers, change the message for that field and display it. If there are multiple messages, I only would like to display the first one.

Problem is: I don't know where to start exactly, I can hardly type the same html/css/JQuery again with a different names for a different function, cause that would mean a lot of the same code and that's not good coding. Hope you can help me, or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a fiddle and upload u r code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z975b1d8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `validate` function you can add another `if`. 
something like

```
if( $(input).attr('type') == 'text' && $(input).val().length > 10 ) {
  return false;
}
```

this will:

- check if input type is 'text'
- check if it's value is longer than 10 char

for checking if string or 'password' contains special chars you can use something like this:

```
if( $(input).attr('type') == 'password' && /^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test($(input).val()) != false) {
  return false;
}
```

and again
this will:

- check if input type is 'password'
- check if it's value contains only lowercase chars, uppercase chars and digits (check regex, it's very useful in validation and much more)

The rest depends on your imagination :)

Comment: Ok, and how would I change the message? I can't give a message that the field is not filled in when the password is not correct

Comment: My idea:
change `return false` to something like `return "bad password or something"`

after `if($(input).val().trim() == ''){ ... }` place `else { return true; }`

then in 'onSubmit' function change
`if(validate(input[i]) === false){`
to something like
`var test = validate(input[i]); if(test !== true) { gather message from test and change showValidate function to display given error }`